# How to change the SWAP file disk in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, performance, mac, performance-tuning, swap

I have moved my system on andexternal Raid 1 enclosure attachet to my iMac through Firewire 800 (the best an iMac can do ;-( ) ...

I'd like to move the swap on the internal disk in order to increase somehow the performances ...

How can I achieve this task?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of OSX, its different in 10.4 or earlier to 10.5

Comment: Leopard in specific, but it is for sake of knowledge, so I'd like to know in general :) Got LapTop006 answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the 10.4 (Tiger) and 10.3 (Panther) solution:

http://www.math.columbia.edu/~bayer/OSX/swapfile/

And here's the 10.5 (Leopard) version:

http://www.sysarchitects.com/node/90

Of course it probably makes more sense to just add enough RAM that you don't swap, it's really cheap to have 4GB in any machine these days.

Comment: Thanks for the links AapTop006.

I agree that RAM is cheap, I already have 4GB RAM in fact, but I'd like to be able to maximize my system as much as I can. :)